# How to calculate epsilon for DBSCAN when there is only one dimension

Tags: dbscan

In the examples of DBSCAN I have see the epsilon is calculated using euclidean distance 
[image]

I am trying to find outlier of system metrics. I am trying to implement something similar to http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/07/tracking-down-villains-outlier.html?m=1. Snippet from the article

> This window is then passed to the DBSCAN algorithm, which returns the
>   set of servers considered outliers

If the metrics I am measuring is CPU utilization of the servers how would i calculate epsilon? Should it be like the one below?

[image]

any suggestion would be helpful on implementation

Comment: Do you have just a single dimension, or are you asking about Manhattan distance?

Comment: yes I have a whole bunch of CPU metrics of various systems. as a pre processing  I read data in 5 min slots and average the CPU utilization metrics for each of the systems.Since I have only only CPU utilization mertrics i am considering it one dimensional (not sure if I am correct or not) So if i want to implement something similar to netflix how do i calculate distance based on the information I have?